# Making a function loopable in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I'm trying to loop over `f` in my R code below. But `f` itself is a function (i.e., `is.function(f)` gives `TRUE`).

I'm wondering given that `f` is a function, is it possible to loop over it?

***Note:*** `f` comes from `f <- approxfun(...)` and needs to remain as a function so I can use `integrate(f, ...)`.

Here is my R code:

```
den = list()
x = rep(0, 2)
d = list(c(rbeta(1e4, 5, 5), rbeta(1e4, 2, 5)))
f = as.function()       ## What should this be? ##

for(i in 1:2){
den[[i]] <- density(d[[i]])
f[i] <- approxfun(den[[i]]$x, den[[i]]$y, yleft = 0, yright = 0) # how can it become loopable?
x[i] <- integrate(f[i], 0, .1)[[1]]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following, `class(f[1])` is a `list` while `class(f[[1]])` is a `function`. So, you simply need to have `f[[i]]` in the `integrate` function.

```
den = list()
x = rep(0, 2)

d <- list()
d[[1]] <- rbeta(1e4, 5, 5) 
d[[2]] <- rbeta(1e4, 2, 5)

f <- list()     

for(i in 1:2){

  den[[i]] <- density(d[[i]])
  f[[i]] <- approxfun(den[[i]]$x, den[[i]]$y, yleft = 0, yright = 0) 
  x[i] <- integrate(f[[i]], 0, .1)[[1]]

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Though there already is an accepted answer, I will post mine, since I believe that the main error in your code comes from trying too hard, you are complicating too much.

First of all, you don't need a list of functions `f`, you only need one function to use with `integrate`, like you say in the question.

Second, the way you created `d` uses an unnecessary call to `c`. This call will make of its arguments *one* vector, not two vectors of random beta numbers, which is what you want.

So the full code is just a simplification of yours.

```
set.seed(4149)    # makes the results reproducible

den = list()
x = rep(0, 2)
d = list(rbeta(1e4, 5, 5), rbeta(1e4, 2, 5))

for(i in 1:2){
    den[[i]] <- density(d[[i]])
    f <- approxfun(den[[i]]$x, den[[i]]$y, yleft = 0, yright = 0) # how can it become loopable?
    x[i] <- integrate(f, 0, .1)[[1]]
}

x
#[1] 0.001244482 0.110921241
```

Note the call to `set.seed`, when using RNG's it is a good idea to set the seed, in order to have reproducible data and results.